# return value for method asynchronous

Tags: c#, json

I have a homepage where I call a class that reads a JSON with an asynchronous method, this method works good, but I need to return the value of the JSON to the main page.

MainPage.cs,

```
private void btnPrueba_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{


Dictionary<string,string> parametros = new Dictionary<string,string>();
parametros.Add("login", "12345678R");
parametros.Add("password", "123123");

objPrueba = new prueba();

objPrueba.doPost("http://prueba.es/login", parametros);

}
```

Class Post.cs,

```
public void doPost(string url, Dictionary<string, string> parametros)
{
System.Uri myUri = new System.Uri(url);
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
myRequest.Method = "POST";
myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

//relleno variable con los parametros
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> D in parametros)
{
parametrosData = parametrosData + D.Key + "=";
parametrosData = parametrosData + D.Value + "&";
}


bool a = myRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), myRequest).IsCompleted;

string b = "1231232";


}


void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
{
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
// End the stream request operation
Stream postStream = myRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);

// Create the post data
string postData = parametrosData;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

// Add the post data to the web request
postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
postStream.Close();

// Start the web request




myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new System.AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), myRequest);
}

void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
{
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackRe sult);
using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
string result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
//For debug: show results
Debug.WriteLine(result);

//RETURN VALUE result TO MAINPAGE.CS



}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use asynchronous functions, this would make your code much simpler.

You would have something like: (sorry for the bad formatting, I'm not familiar yet with StackOverflow editor...)

```
public async Task<string> doPost(string url, Dictionary<string, string> parametros)
{

System.Uri myUri = new System.Uri(url);
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);
myRequest.Method = "POST";
myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

//relleno variable con los parametros
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> D in parametros)
{
parametrosData = parametrosData + D.Key + "=";
parametrosData = parametrosData + D.Value + "&";
}

Stream postStream = await myRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync();

// Create the post data
string postData = parametrosData;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

// Add the post data to the web request
postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
postStream.Close();

// Start the web request

HttpWebResponse response = await myRequest.GetResponseAsync();

string result;

using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
 result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();


//For debug: show results
Debug.WriteLine(result);
}

return result;
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
private async void btnPrueba_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{


Dictionary<string,string> parametros = new Dictionary<string,string>();
parametros.Add("login", "12345678R");
parametros.Add("password", "123123");

objPrueba = new prueba();

string result = await objPrueba.doPost("http://prueba.es/login", parametros);

// You can use the string to update the GUI if you want, because this code is running on the GUI thread

}
```

Comment: 1) You should use a `WebClient` for task based asynchrony when making a web request. 2) To format your code just format it in VS before you copy it over to SO.